# What is meant by magnitude of the forces?

Tags: forces, momentum

Okay so I wanted to know what is meant when a questions asks for the magnitude of the forces or anything for that matter. For example if you have two cars that collide with each other, both at the same speeds with the same I assume that the magnitudes of the force would be similar to each one?

Answer (score 0):

Forces are vectors which means they have a magnitude and a direction.  The magnitude of the force is just the number of newtons.

In the case of the car collision the magnitude of the force the first car exerts on the second would be exactly the same as the magnitude of the force the second car exerts on the first though the directions would be opposite - Newton's Third Law.

Comment: Thank you so much! I think i was just making it more complicated then it needed to be but it all makes sense now!